# Robotframework integrated with a testing tool

Tags: testing, load, robotframework, grinder

Is anyone aware of any ongoing open source project that integrates robotframework with a load testing tool such as grinder, jmeter, funkload etc?

Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate on what you have in mind? I am in line with David's answer and don't see how a Func Tests tools would need to be integrated with a Load testing tool. Both can just live side by side and be "integrated" by Jenkins if you want a single dashboard where you see all your testing job.

Comment: I would like to run load tests verifying at the same time that the responses received are the correct ones and therefore the system still works correctly from a functional point of view under load. So I was planning to reuse the test set written in robotframework for that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There is a Python library for integration of Robot Framework and JMeter: [Robot Framework JMeter Library](https://github.com/kowalpy/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library) . It can be used for running JMeter and parsing and converting results. I am author of this library so I might not be objective.

Comment: Library homepage moved from sourceforge to https://github.com/kowalpy/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library

Answer (score 0):

No, and that's likely not to happen. Robot Framework is for functional not load testing. How would you deem a load test as pass/fail and how long does it run?

Robot Framework and functional tests have a finite set execution time (takes as long as it needs to complete testing the particular feature or times out before doing so in case it hung, etc.), and has strict criteria as to what is pass/fail when test runs.

With load testing, you at least during exploratory runs and design of test, you don't run for fixed time, or even if fixed, it's usually not short (except trial runs and scalable burst increases). And criteria for pass/fail is usually within ranges rather than yes/no.

So it's harder to integrate and design a test library that can offer pass/fail and run within some set time for load testing. Unless someone can define a good architectural design of a test and test library for how to do so with Robot Framework.

Answer (score -1):

I think the idea would be that a test case is created only once and can be used in both functional tests as in load tests and even in end user monitoring. In this (utopic) way a test case can be used during the whole lifecycle of an application. With a tag (for instance) a test case can be promoted to be also a loadtesting test case with another type of response validation. Would be nice to run Robot framework and create a Loadrunner-TrueClient (or another browser-driven loadtesttool) script. Main purpose of the integration would be to automate the scripting.